# Combine Multiple Lists into a JSON file with different indention levels

Tags: python, json, list, csv, wmic

****edit: I need the key:value pairs of the printers data to go under a "topic/flag" of that printers name.**

I am trying to get the output of `wmic printer list brief` and turn it into a JSON file for storage and parsing at a later date. So far I have gotten it into CSV format with the `/format:csv` flag and have gotten it where I can go through and turn that CSV data into a list. The problem is the formatting of the json. How can I format the json where all of the data is under the 'flag' of 'Name'? I know that I am not explaining this like I should be but I am stumped. Here is an example of what I want it to look like,

```
{
    "Adobe PDF": {
        "Node": "____________",
        "Location": "____________",
    "PrinterState": "____________",
    "PrinterStatus": "____________",
    "ShareName": "____________",
    "SystemName": "____________"
    }
    "OneNote for Windows 10": {
        "Node": "____________",
        "Location": "____________",
    "PrinterState": "____________",
    "PrinterStatus": "____________",
    "ShareName": "____________",
    "SystemName": "____________"
    }
}
```

On another note how can I clean up and compress this python code to make it more efficient and take up less space?

Python Code:

```
import csv
import json

Node = []
Location = []
Name = []
PrinterState = []
PrinterStatus = []
ShareName = []
SystemName = []


csvfile = getprinters()
reader = [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile.decode('utf-8').splitlines())]
for i in reader:
if i == []:
    continue
else:
    item1 = i[0]
    item2 = i[1]
    item3 = i[2]
    item4 = i[3]
    item5 = i[4]
    item6 = i[5]
    item7 = i[6]
    Node.append(item1)
    Location.append(item2)
    Name.append(item3)
    PrinterState.append(item4)
    PrinterStatus.append(item5)
    ShareName.append(item6)
    SystemName.append(item7)
```

Starting CSV:

```
Node,Location,Name,PrinterState,PrinterStatus,ShareName,SystemName
COMPUTERNAME,,Adobe PDF,0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME,,OneNote for Windows 10,0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME,,OneNote (Desktop),0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME,,Microsoft XPS Document Writer,0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME,,Microsoft Print to PDF,0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME,http://12.345.6.789:0000/,HP###### (HP Officejet Pro 8610),0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME,,Fax,0,3,,COMPUTERNAME
```

Example List:

```
['Node', 'COMPUTERNAME', 'COMPUTERNAME', 'COMPUTERNAME', 'COMPUTERNAME', 'COMPUTERNAME','COMPUTERNAME', 'COMPUTERNAME']
```

Comment: You do understand that formatting/indentation has no practical purpose in JSON, right? It's purely for visual effect/appearance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what else to call it, let me try to explain it better. I need the key:value pairs of the printers data to go under a "topic/flag" of that printers name.

Comment: Create a dict with the printer name as key and the according data as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the csv file, with `csv.DictReader`. Create a dict and dump that dict into JSON. The `dict` will become JSON Object.

```
import csv
import json

with open('start.csv') as f:
    rdr =  csv.DictReader(f)
    data = {row.get('Name'):row for row in rdr} # use row.pop('Name') if you want to remove Name key from row

with open('export.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

the output `export.json`:

```
{
    "Adobe PDF": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "",
        "Name": "Adobe PDF",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    },
    "OneNote for Windows 10": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "",
        "Name": "OneNote for Windows 10",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    },
    "OneNote (Desktop)": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "",
        "Name": "OneNote (Desktop)",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    },
    "Microsoft XPS Document Writer": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "",
        "Name": "Microsoft XPS Document Writer",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    },
    "Microsoft Print to PDF": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "",
        "Name": "Microsoft Print to PDF",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    },
    "HP###### (HP Officejet Pro 8610)": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "http://12.345.6.789:0000/",
        "Name": "HP###### (HP Officejet Pro 8610)",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    },
    "Fax": {
        "Node": "COMPUTERNAME",
        "Location": "",
        "Name": "Fax",
        "PrinterState": "0",
        "PrinterStatus": "3",
        "ShareName": "",
        "SystemName": "COMPUTERNAME"
    }
}
```

Comment: It just outputs this: `{
    "null": {
        "null": [
            "NOAHBLAUT",
            "",
            "Fax",
            "0",
            "3",
            "",
            "NOAHBLAUT"
        ]
    }
}

Comment: This snippet is tested with your sample csv and it works just fine. I updated my answer with the output it produce from your sample.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me check it out. Sorry :(

Comment: Note, I didn't convert the numbers, because you did not do that in your code.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! You were right, it was the way I was handling the data in the background that caused the error.